# Por que algumas variáveis Javascript são declaradas com underline _?

Tags: javascript

Exemplo que encontrei na internet:

```
var _iterator = require("../core-js/symbol/iterator");

var _iterator2 = _interopRequireDefault(_iterator);

var _symbol = require("../core-js/symbol");

var _symbol2 = _interopRequireDefault(_symbol);

var _typeof = typeof _symbol2.default === "function" && typeof _iterator2.default === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof _symbol2.default === "function" && obj.constructor === _symbol2.default && obj !== _symbol2.default.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É uma convenção para dizer que essas propriedades são privadas.
Abaixo segue link, com exemplos, de um guia de estilos para JavaScript:
[Convenções de nomenclatura](https://snowdream.github.io/javascript-style-guide/javascript-style-guide/br/naming-conventions.html)